# Micro-graphics inline in text

Tags: graphics, inline

Can I insert a graphic in-line in a sentence?

---

Use case: I'm writing a manual that involves navigating the Windows Start Menu. I would like to insert a little graphic of the start menu in-line in the text. I am aware of a `sparklines` package that does something similar, but have not been able to distill that to a simple example.

Is there a macro or command that can help with this?

In addition (and I hope this is a valid part of the question, but am happy to post it as a new question) I would like a shortcut or command to display the Windows Start Menu plus `n` steps of navigation, so I could write the following:

```
Some paragraph and then \WinMenu{Start}{Programs}{Foo}{Bar}{Baz.exe} and then more text.
```

or

```
Lorem ipsum \WinMenu{Programs,Foo,Bar,Baz.exe} and then more text.
```

or something similar, and the result in the PDF will be stylized somehow, with the little Start Menu box icon (shown as "GRAPHIC" below), and then, for example, in bold or `\tttext` fonts, `GRAPHIC > Foo > Bar > Baz.exe` as part of and embedded in the existing sentence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the selected answer by @Peter I implemented it like so. Please excuse (or edit!) formatting errors below:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\StartMenu}{\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{start.pdf}}%
\newcommand{\WinMenu}[1]{%
   \StartMenu
   \texttt{\,Start$>$Programs}%
   \foreach \x in {#1} {%
   \texttt{$>$\x}%    
   }%
}%
```

It looks better to have the word "Start" be in the same font as the rest of the text. I am also lazy and do not want to type "Start,Programs" each time, so they are hard coded. Use case is: `Also, \WinMenu{Foo,Bar,Baz} and some text` and result is:

[image: Sample showing WinMenu command]

The vertical alignment of the icon is off by a tiny bit, but it is good enough for my purposes.

Comment: The vertical alignment can easily be corrected with \raisebox (\raisebox{-.5ex}{\includegraphics{whatever.jpg}})

Answer (score 20):

Here is one way to do it. I took the liberty to add some formatting, but feel free to change it as you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\WineMenuColor}{black}%
\newcommand*{\StartMenu}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{StartIcon}}%
\newcommand*{\WinMenu}[1]{%
\StartMenu %
\foreach \x in {#1} {%
    $\boldsymbol{\textcolor{\WineMenuColor}{>}}$ \texttt{\textcolor{\WineMenuColor}{\x}}%
}}%

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \WinMenu{Programs,Foo,Bar,Baz.exe} and then more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution. I will post my version (based off an earlier version of yours) for reference.

Comment: Isn't it possible to define image size based on font size, just like in HTML?

Comment: @TomášZato: I am not that familiar with HTML and think you should post separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution: use `\includegrapchis` and play a bit with the picture size. But you have to do it for each font size.

Concerning menu: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/menu

> Menu.sty define a command `\menu{Programm!!Menu1!Command}` and expand it
>   to something like Programm=>Menu1->Command.  You can use it for
>   documentations of programs.

If you solved your main question (inline Micro-graphics) you may combine it with menu.sty.