# Allowing hyphenation in menu sequences

Tags: hyphenation

I've adapted Peter Grill's `\Menu` command in [Create a command for 'menu sequences'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40613/create-a-command-for-menu-sequences/40618#40618) to type menu sequences in some documents. It looks like hyphenation is not allowed inside these menu sequences and I'd like to allow it. How can I do it?

As you can see from next code, hyphenation is working outside `\menu`

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{FirstOne}%
\newcommand*{\menu}[1]{%
   \toggletrue{FirstOne}%
   \foreach \x in {#1} {%
      \iftoggle{FirstOne}{}{${}\rightarrow{}$}%
      \texttt{\x}%
      \global\togglefalse{FirstOne}%
   }%
}%

\begin{document}
Configura la simulació per analitzar les següents \emph{Global Statistics}:

    Configura la simulació per analitzar les següents \menu{Global Statistics}:
\begin{itemize}
\item \menu{Traffic Sink, Traffic Received (bist/sec).} Marca també la casella \menu{Generate scalar data} i selecciona \menu{sample mean} del menú desplegable.
\item \menu{Traffic Source, Traffic Sent (bist/sec).} Marca també la casella \menu{Generate scalar data} i selecciona \menu{sample mean} del menú desplegable.
\item \menu{Node Statistics, Ethcoax, Collision Count} i \menu{Transmission attempts}.
\item \menu{Node Statistics, Traffic Sink, Traffic Received (bist/sec).}
\item \menu{Node Statistics, Traffic Source, Traffic Sent (bist/sec).}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\texttt` disables hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I didn't know it. Can I get a typewritter aspect with any other command?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt) for how to do hyphenation of tt text. You might as well also want to use something else than typewriter font for Menus. With the package `menu` there is a command `\menutext` for changing how menus are rendered.

Comment: `menukeys` is pretty nice.