# Figure in text body

Tags: graphics

I would like to put a picture in text body as shown in the following picture from MS Word.

[image: Image in test]

I tried some things but not working. What I want is more or less the `\LaTex` command but for my image!

Is there any way to do this in latex?

Comment: related: [Micro-graphics inline in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28914/579).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use

```
I studied in \includegraphics[height=0.8em]{tudelftlogo}.
```

or perhaps

```
I studied in \includegraphics[height=0.8em]{tudelftlogo}Delft.
```

depending whether the final Delft is part of the image.

and add `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: hahaha! I could not imagine that it is so easy!
Thank you very much :)