# How to format labels of user interface elements?

Tags: formatting

I am writing a document using LaTeX which describes an application I have developed. I refer to some buttons or sections of my application in the document and I want to format them in a special way. How can I do this?

Examples for these user interface labels could be "File -> Print" or the "OK" button.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Command with variable number of arguments to format menu sequences](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101312/5764)

Comment: Other related Questions: [Micro-graphics inline in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28914/micro-graphics-inline-in-text), and [Create a command for 'menu sequences'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40613/create-a-command-for-menu-sequences).