# Adding a bar graph in resume for skills

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, cv

I want to add skills using bar graphs in my resume. How do I do that? I want similar to this.[image]

Comment: Hello and Welcome. Could you show us what you do so far ? see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: i am new to latex and have seen in one of the templates, \skills being used in this way-\skills{{pursuer of rabbits/5.8},{good manners/4},{outgoing/4.3},{polite/4},{Java/0.01}}

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please do this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Close voters: I think that a new user deserves more than one hours grace!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-line graphics in text to represent a loading bar for language skills in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238898/in-line-graphics-in-text-to-represent-a-loading-bar-for-language-skills-in-a-cv)

Comment: Close voters: although similar, line indicators are different from half-filled dots. This said, the OP should add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: You can find an example of command `\skills` in [make-tikzpicture-automatically-insert-page-break-at-bottom-of-the-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416094/1952)

Answer (score 8):

Simple basic code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {Java};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (.1,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {polite};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {outgoing};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {good manners};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{.05cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] at (.1,.8) {pursuer of rabbits};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,.5);
\draw [fill={rgb:red,1;green,2;blue,3}] (0,0) rectangle (4.8,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know it's late, but here is the code I extracted from the [example](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv) where you made the screenshot:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,gray](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node[above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\skills{{b/2}}
\skills{{a/1}}
\end{document}
```