# How to reduce space between entrys in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

For my CV I'd like to use some [skillbars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331820/adding-a-bar-graph-in-resume-for-skills/416198#416198).

But since my layout is fixed I need to adjust the space between the entries.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,gray](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node[above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\skills{{a/1},{b/2}}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the code to define/decrease the space between the two entries?

Comment: May be you want to consider another version of `skills` command which can break between pages for large lists of skills: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416094/1952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you need to reduce size if `\i` for example with multiplying it by `0.8`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\newcommand\skills[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach [count=\j, evaluate={\i=\j*0.8}] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle +(6,0.4); % <---
            \draw[fill=white,gray](0,\i) rectangle +(\y,0.4);% <---
            \node[above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};% <---
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\skills{{a/1},{b/2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Slightly more flexible, requiring less modifications: `\foreach [count=\j, evaluate={\i=\j*0.75}]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., you have right. i will edit my answer and consider your comment.

Comment: The updated version of your code works just fine for me, thank you very much :-)