# Creating a bar filled only by a portion in aside

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I was trying to modify this [cv](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) by adding the bar indicators i found in this other [cv](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv) under the skills section but I wasn't able to adapt it. Is there a way to do it?

To be clear I would like to have different bars which I can fill by a percentage with another color and the bars are place in an "aside" environment.

I have an environment aside

```
\begin{document} 
    \begin{aside}
        \section{Abilities} 
    \end{aside} 
\end{document}
```

In the abilites section I would like to insert a bar like these

[image]

I've tried using this command:

```
\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\skills}{ 
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{ 
                \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4); 
                \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4); 
                \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x}; } 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    } 
}
```

But I can't make it work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050).

Comment: I have an environment aside

`\begin{document}
\begin{aside} 
\section{Abilities}
\end{aside}
\end{document}`


In the abilites section I would like to insert a bar like these

[img](https://imgur.com/a/282eG)

I've tried using this command:

`\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
 \renewcommand{\skills}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
   \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
   \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
   \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
}
`
But I can't make it work.

Comment: I would like something like this
![img](http://imgur.com/a/282eG)

Comment: You could edit your question. Please add your code with \documentclass and \end{document} to your question. You could also include your image directly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-line graphics in text to represent a loading bar for language skills in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238898/in-line-graphics-in-text-to-represent-a-loading-bar-for-language-skills-in-a-cv)

Comment: Close voters: although similar, line indicators are different from half-filled dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not take a look at your links. The following does print some bars with skills above of them. I don't know how good it fits into your existing code. Also I do not know the `aside` environment.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=4mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{noskillgray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{skilledblue}{rgb}{0.05,0.05,0.65}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\skillb@level
\newdimen\skillb@length
\newdimen\skillb@height
\skillb@length=120pt%
\skillb@height=10pt%
\newcommand*{\skillbar}[1]{%
    \skillb@level=\dimexpr#1\skillb@length/100\relax%
    {\color{skilledblue}\rule{\skillb@level}{\skillb@height}}%
    {\color{noskillgray}%
        \rule{\dimexpr\skillb@length-\skillb@level\relax}{\skillb@height}}%
}
\newcommand*{\skill}[2]{%
    \par\noindent%
    {\hskip 1ex\small #1}\\%
    \skillbar{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\skill{Java}{1}
\skill{polite}{59}
\skill{outgoing}{69}
\skill{good manners}{63}
\skill{pursuer of rabbits}{94}
\skill{clueless}{99}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Sorry for answering so late but I ha a couple of busy days! Your code works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help!