# Add small graph chart to indicate the skill level in a resume

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have taken the solution of [In-line graphics in the text to represent a loading bar for language skills in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238898/in-line-graphics-in-text-to-represent-a-loading-bar-for-language-skills-in-a-cv) and adapted to my current resume. Although I only use three levels and I like the result, it still consumes a lot of space.

So, I want to put a small graph chart next to the skills, like this:

[image]

Could you help me to create a command to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here `tikz` is overkill. The bar graph can be realized with `\rule`. The `xcolor` package is needed to get the lighter color. The command `\skillevel` adapts automatically to the current font height (with `\settoheight`) and the current color. The argument is the number of bars with the current text color. The optional argument can be used change how much the color is lightened (0 - 100, the smaller number, the lighter the color).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newdimen\slheight
\newcommand{\skillevel}[2][20]{%
  \begingroup
  \settoheight{\slheight}{M}%
  \ifnum#2=0\color{.!#1}\fi
  \rule{.1em}{.33333\slheight}\hspace{.1em}%
  \ifnum#2=1\color{.!#1}\fi
  \rule{.1em}{.66667\slheight}\hspace{.1em}%
  \ifnum#2=2\color{.!#1}\fi
  \rule{.1em}{\slheight}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{\textsf{\tiny\skillevel{0} \LaTeX}}
\textcolor{red}{\textsf{\skillevel{1} \LaTeX}}
\textcolor{teal}{\textsf{\skillevel{2} \LaTeX}}
\textcolor{green}{\textsf{\Large\skillevel{3} \LaTeX}}
\textcolor{cyan}{\textsf{\Huge\skillevel{2} \LaTeX}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may also have a look to the CTAN package sparklines: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sparklines

Comment: The result is amazing. However, as I found the graph a bit small I adjusted the height (among other values) to be greater than the font size. May I ask you, how can I create an offset of the graph from the row? I mean, to start the `\rule` under the row.

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice that the `\rule` command have already that parameter: `\rule[raise]{width}{thickness}`. I added it to the code above and it works like a charm.