# LaTex: CV/resume support

Tags: formatting, cv

Hopefully, someone can help me with my problem.

I have tried to implement the following code from an old post in my cv project:
[In-line graphics in text to represent a loading bar for language skills in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238898/in-line-graphics-in-text-to-represent-a-loading-bar-for-language-skills-in-a-cv)

Unfortunately, I failed :(

My code:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/rgskjktntgdf

The design and colours should remain as they are, I just want the possibility to fill these circle half.

Looking forward to getting help form you :)

Best,
Andreas

Comment: Well, what did "I failed" mean? Did you get error messages? Which one? Please explain better and show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper answer to this question was provided by Jojo in another thread.

please check the following post for the answer:
[semi filled circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538853/semi-filled-circle/539280)

Best, 
Andreas