# Micro-graphics in caption environment

Tags: captions

I am using my own icons in a document using

`\newcommand{\icon}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{myicon.pdf}}`

as described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28914/micro-graphics-inline-in-text).

Now I am trying to use this newcommand in a caption environment, but I get errors

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
```

Is there any way to add figures to the caption environment? or any suggested workaround to this?

---

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\icon}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{myicon.pdf}}

\begin{document}

This is an inline \icon % this part compiles good

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myfigure}
\caption{This is an \icon in a caption environment.} % this part gives errors
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a small complete code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you probably have a newer graphics package

Comment: "New *and improved*", isn't that how the saying goes @DavidCarlisle?  Like a box of detergent.  "Now with a **brighter** color palatte!!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent releases `\includegraphics` is robust so should not prematurely expand when writing the `.toc` file, but in any release you could define your command via

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myicon}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{myicon.pdf}}
```

then it will not expand in moving environments.

Unrelated you may prefer to use something like `height=1.1ex` rather than `scale=0.2` then the icon will adjust to font size commands such as `\large`.

Comment: This works just perfect, thank you! I had no idea about `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: @Saavestro  I really shouldn't have posted yet now I need to get another accept quickly if I'm to get 555,555 :)

Comment: Just hope nobody downvotes you...that will really screw up your numerological aspirations.  But I won't upvote, so as to keep you in reach of your goal.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have upvoted :(

Comment: @Sebastiano Maybe 5 of us could downvote to counteract!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I can't. Just my last downwote it is since 2018. :-) and I would hold my average :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Fear not. David is resourceful.  He can always stack the deck and delete one of his lesser answers to reset the count.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ahahahaahahhahah LOL :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am honored to have found the master of LaTeX.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes or simply get another answer accepted, I'm back on track:-)